# Coordinates in Basemap don't match the real ones

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

For my team project I'm trying to obtain a map of my city using Python and plot a heatmap on it. I'm using Basemap and matplotlib.

I found that selecting epsg=3003 gives sufficient graphic results, but the problem is that if I want to visualize a precise coordinate on the map, for example lat=45.0306 and long=7.42, it shows a different point with respect to the one I get with Google Earth.

Since I need to plot data with very precise and near coordinates, getting an accurate map is essential.

Can anyone help me with my code?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

map = Basemap(llcrnrlat=45,urcrnrlat=45.4,
    llcrnrlon=7.41,urcrnrlon=7.8,resolution='h', epsg=3003)
map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels = 3000, verbose= True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using two different projection systems. Google Earth uses WGS84, whose epsg code is: 3857 but you set up your map using EPSG:3003. The best would simply be to change the projection of your map when you define your basemap. Alternatively, if you really want to use EPSG:3003 then you have to reproject the coordinate you get from Google Earth (you may want to have a look at this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77573/129792))

Here a small example to show that by using the proper projection you can nicely match google map results:

```
map = Basemap(llcrnrlat=45.245,urcrnrlat=45.255,
      llcrnrlon=7.54,urcrnrlon=7.55,resolution='h', epsg=4326)
map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels = 3000, verbose= True)
plt.plot(7.544335,45.250423,marker='+',markersize=15,color='Red')
```

Here the map from basemap with a google map screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I tried your code and I see a completely blank map and I don't know why, just espg=3003 seems to work for me. Do you have any suggestion on the reason that causes it?

Comment: which version of matplotlib and basemap are you using?

Comment: but in any case your problem is fundamentally a projection issue, so if you need to work a lot with google earth you should really change the projection of your map. Alternatively you can write a script to reproject WGS84 coordinate into EPSG:3003

Comment: Matplotlib 3.1.1, Basemap 3.7.

Comment: I'll have a lot of data with relative latitude and longitude to plot but I don't need to use google earth, it was just to check that the coordinates on my map match the ones that I'll get with a GPS.

Comment: well, then you have to check the projection of your GPS and make sure it matches with your map. It's always the same principle. Concerning basemap, you mean python 3.7 right? The latest version of [basemap is 1.2.1](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/index.html)

Comment: If you are starting a new project you should also consider to use [Cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) instead of matplotlib. In fact [basemap is deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/intro.html#deprecation-notice) and it will not be maintained anymore from 2020.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I'll switch to Cartopy! Yeah the version was 1.2.1.